# wp-e-commerce plugin - custom payment option

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

**How to add "Cash on delivery"** in payments options? Also if that option is selected, user should get "invoice" by email. I'm using wp-e-commerce plugin.

Comment: I'm having issues with Test Gateway. The main one is that I don't get eMail notifications as soon as a new order has arrived, which is obviously is not (yet) paid for. With other payment gateways, afaik, this problem is not relevant, since you get notification once the order has been paid online.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Test Gateway" option under the Payment tab in Store Settings, you can then enter a display name of "Cash on Delivery", and add any other instructions in there.